# ASP.Net & MVC 4 MvcContrib.UI.Grid - @Html.Action (PartialViewResult) vs @Html.Partial

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, grid, mvccontrib

We're currently testing MvcContrib.UI.Grid and it seems to suit our needs well.

What is intriguiging is that @Html.Grid's sorting action links don't work if we call view through @Html.Action -syntax returning PartialViewResult.
@Html.Partion -syntax works without problems.

#### Action link using @Html.Action - PartialViewResult (doesn't work)

```
http://localhost:26952/Electoral/PartialCandidates?Column=last_name&Direction=Ascending
```

#### Action link using @Html.Partial (works)

```
http://localhost:26952/03/481/last_name/Ascending
```

#### PartialCandidates.vbhtml

```
@Imports MvcContrib.UI.Grid
@Imports MvcContrib.Sorting

@ModelType Global.kuntavaalit2012.Models.Candidates

@If Model.Candidates.Count > 0 Then
@Html.Grid(Model.Candidates).Columns(Function(column) {
    column.For(Function(c) String.Format("{0}, {1}", c.last_name, c.first_name)).Named("Nimi").SortColumnName("last_name").Sortable(True),
    column.For(Function(c) c.age).Named("Ikä").SortColumnName("age").Sortable(True),
    column.For(Function(c) Model.Nominator(c.nominator_Id).name).Named("Puolue").SortColumnName("nominator_Id").Sortable(True),
    column.For(Function(c) c.advance_votes).Named("Ennakkoäänet").SortColumnName("advance_votes").Sortable(True),
    column.For(Function(c) c.election_day_votes).Named("Vaalipäivän äänet").SortColumnName("election_day_votes").Sortable(True),
    column.For(Function(c) c.total_votes).Named("Äänet yhteensä").SortColumnName("total_votes").Sortable(True)
}).Sort(CType(ViewData("sort"), GridSortOptions))
End If
```

Has anyone stumbled into this before?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Esa